How to get the "normal" text Euro sign in siunix using \qty
I want to have the same Euro sign in the \qty{...}{...} options as in the text. MWE:
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\DeclareSIUnit{\EUR}{\texteuro}


\begin{document}
    
This is the sign I want when using siunitx: €\\

Example 1: \qty{1}{€}   

Example 2: \qty{1}{\EUR}

Example 3: \qty{1}{\texteuro}

\end{document}

...results in:

I found some advide saying that the eurosym package and gensymb package together with \DeclareSIUnit{\EUR}{\texteuro} should do the trick - but it does not help.
Edit: the solution suggested below using this code:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\EUR}{\text{\texteuro}}
\begin{document}
    
    This is the sign I want when using siunitx: €\\
    
    Example 1: \qty[unit-mode = text]{1}{€}   
    
    Example 2: \qty{1}{\EUR}
    
    Example 3: \qty[unit-mode = text]{1}{\texteuro}
    
\end{document}

results in this Euro sign: (which differs from the one I want, see above)


I guess you want eurosym in order to use the “official” Euro glyph.
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[right]{eurosym}
\DeclareSIUnit{\EUR}{\text{\officialeuro}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\officialeuro}

\begin{document}

This is the sign I want when using siunitx: €

Example 1: \qty{1}{\EUR}

\end{document}

Note \text, so siunitx doesn't try to use math mode, where \officialeuro is invalid as well as \texteuro.
If you prefer \texteuro, don't load eurosym and replace \officialeuro with \texteuro (the \DeclareUnicodeCharacter line is unneeded, in this case).


Thanks - this worked. Your sencond suggestion is what I intended.

@FantasticMsFox I hope you don't really want the obnoxious symbol you get with the default font.

Why not? It fits much better with the latin modern font and symbols in the rest of the document. And I don´t see that there is a norm or ISO standard that would forbid that?!

@FantasticMsFox That glyph is a very unfortunate decision made by the developer of the European Modern fonts. There is a EU regulation that says to use the official symbol if available, but a “C” with two bars is acceptable. This said, use the glyph you want but don't be surprised if readers don't understand it or, in the worst case, laugh.

:D thank you - I will reconsider my decision

The euro symbol is a text mode character, so you need units in text mode here for this to work:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\EUR}{\text{\texteuro}}
\begin{document}
  
This is the sign I want when using siunitx: €\\

Example 1: \qty[unit-mode = text]{1}{€}   

Example 2: \qty{1}{\EUR}

Example 3: \qty[unit-mode = text]{1}{\texteuro}

\end{document}


this doesn´t work for me - if I run your code, the Euro sign looks strange - definitely not the one I want.

@FantasticMsFox You will have to define 'strange' here - the code simply uses the current text mode euro symbol that  you'd get elsewhere in your doc

sorry - I edited the question
